# Conditional Distinct in MYSQL with respect o another column

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I have query as follow

```
SELECT * FROM content_type_product cp
JOIN content_field_product_manufacturer cf ON cf.nid = cp.nid group by cp.nid
ORDER
  BY field(cf.field_product_manufacturer_value,'12') DESC,
  cp.field_product_price_value DESC
```

This is working perfect just a small flaw, there are two records having the same id (one is for cf.field_product_manufacturer_value='12' and other is for cf.field_product_manufacturer_value = '57')  which I eliminated using group by clause. But the problem is that I want to get that particular id which has greater "field_product_price_value" but somehow it gives me the value which is lesser. If I query it for '57' then it gives me the id with greater field_product_price_value but when I query it for '12' it gives me id for lesser "field_product_price_value". Is there any way where I can specify to pick the id with greater "field_product_price_value"

Comment: Use a column list and avoid `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `max(field_product_price_value)` combined with appropriate GROUP BY-clause.

In general, you should use `GROUP BY`-clause only when you select both normal columns and aggregate functions (`MIN, MAX, COUNT, AVG`) in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You query is using a (mis)feature of MySQL called Hidden Columns.  This is only advised when all the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` and not in the `GROUP BY` have the same value.  This is not the case, so you need to select the correct records yourself:

```
SELECT cp.*, cf.*
FROM content_type_product cp JOIN
     content_field_product_manufacturer cf
     ON cf.nid = cp.nid join
     (select cf.nid, max(field_product_price_value) as maxprice
      from content_field_product_manufacturer 
      group by cf.nid
     ) cfmax
     on cf.nid = cfmax.nid and cf.field_product_price_value = cfmax.maxprice
ORDER BY field(cf.field_product_manufacturer_value,'12') DESC,
      cp.field_product_price_value DESC
```

Unless you really know what you are doing, when you use a `GROUP BY`, be sure all unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` are in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'2' > '12'
```

if we are talking about varchars. I believe you should convert your field to number type and your sort will work fine. Read this [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) for more information.